# Parallel add and displaced transitions in ListView

Tags: qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

In ListView when I add new item with long add transition inserting new items before that item cause displace of that item and stop its add transition processing. How can I workaround this?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Item
{
    width: 500
    height: 500

    property ListModel model: ListModel {}

    Button
    {
        id: button
        text: "insert: " + model.count

        onClicked:
        {
            model.insert(Math.round(Math.random() * model.count), {"name": model.count});
        }
    }

    ListView
    {
        model: parent.model
        anchors.top: button.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        delegate: Text {
            text: name
        }

        add: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "opacity"; from: 0.0; to: 1.0; duration: 1000 }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is clearly discussed in [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-viewtransition.html) nice tutorial which is really a good read about transitions and their handling. I highly recommend reading it.

Citing it directly from the [Handling interrupted animations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-viewtransition.html#handling-interrupted-animations) section:

> Each newly added item undergoes an add transition, but before the transition can finish, another item is added, displacing the previously added item. Because of this, **the add transition on the previously added item is interrupted and a displaced transition is started on the item instead**. Due to the interruption, the opacity and scale animations have not completed, thus producing items with opacity and scale that are below 1.0.

Hence, what you need is a transition for the displacement. Adding the following code to the `ListView` should solve your issue:

```
displaced: Transition {
    NumberAnimation { properties: "opacity"; to: 1.0; duration: 1000}
}
```

The `duration` can be omitted. It can help to tweak the animation so that speed-ups are avoided (or at least limited). Possibly we can also write:

```
displaced: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { properties: "opacity"; to: 1.0; duration: 1000 * (1 - from)}
}
```

Comment: There is still problem that speed up opacity growth.

Comment: @MateuszDrost Well, on my machine is not so evident. You can try to add the duration and tweak the value (see the edit). You can even try something like `duration: 1000 * (1 - from)`. As said the differences on my machine are so small that it is hard to distinguish particular speed-ups/slow-downs.